# How to export LaTeX snippets to HTML via SVG rather than PNG?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

The org-mode source

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil creator:nil author:nil timestamp:nil num:t validate:nil
#+OPTIONS: tex:imagemagick
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

exports to HTML like a charm. However, the LaTeX snippet is converted to PNG format. Is there a *simple* way to persuade the system to use SVG rather than PNG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the exporter uses Mathjax. You are explicitly over-riding this with the `tex:imagemagick` option, which uses PNG instead. The option `tex:dvisvgm` selects svg format.

See http://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html#Math-formatting-in-HTML-export